# Pointer arithmetic with "inherited" structs is returning unexpected values

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create multiple structs in C with one "base" struct type representing multiple types of objects:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

enum parent_type{
    parent_type_1,
    parent_type_2
};

struct Child{
    int size_bytes;
};

struct Parent1{
    struct Child base;
    u_int16_t val;
};

struct Parent2{
    struct Child base;
    u_int8_t val;
};

void readParentData(struct Child* toread){
    printf("Byte size: %d\n", toread->size_bytes);
    int val_read = *((u_int16_t*)((&toread) + sizeof(struct Child)));
    printf("Value: %d\n", val_read);
}

struct Parent1 p1;

int main(){
    p1.val = 1000;

    p1.base.size_bytes = 2;

    struct Parent1* p1_p = &p1;

    struct Child* child_p = (struct Child*)p1_p;

    readParentData(child_p);
}
```

I would expect readParentData() to output 1000, but instead it is outputting random values. I get the correct output if i cast the pointer to a Parent1 pointer:
`printf("Cast value: %d\n", ((struct Parent1*)(toread))->val);`
but this won't work if I have to use the function for other structs, like Parent2.
I've also tried using the offsetof() function but that gives the same result as my original pointer arithmetic:
`int val_read = *((u_int16_t*)((&toread) + offsetof(struct Parent1, val)));`

I would expect that adding the size of a struct to its pointer gives the address of the next values in the "Parent" struct, but this is apparently not the case.

Comment: [AddressSanitizer](https://godbolt.org/z/fb1TsxxMT) to the rescue. Btw, why not use the standard `typedef`s in `stdint.h`, like `uint16_t` etc. instead of the platform specific ones in `sys/types.h`?

Comment: What is `u_int16_t`?  That is not a standard type.

Comment: There can be padding between `base` and `val` so that `val` will be aligned properly, which isn't included in `sizeof(struct Child)`

Comment: `(&toread)` is the address of the local pointer variable, not the address of the structure it points to. Why would you add anything to that?

Comment: You should just use `((struct Parent1 *)toread)->val`

Comment: You are using the words "child" and "parent" backwards. `Child` is the parent/base class, and `Parent1` and `Parent2` are children of `Child`.

Comment: That's true about Child and Parent being backwards - my mistake. `&toread` is also incorrect, I apologize for the mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((&toread) + sizeof(struct Child)))` is offsetting the address of `toread` by `sizeof(struct Child)`. You need to offset what `toread` points to by `sizeof(struct Child)`. Additionally, offsetting `toread` by `sizeof(struct Child)` adds `sizeof(struct Child) * sizeof(struct Child)`
to `toread`. To offset `toread` by the size of 1 child, you need to add 1 to it.
What you need to do for this to work is

```
void readParentData(struct Child* toread){
    printf("Byte size: %d\n", toread->size_bytes);
    int val_read = *((u_int16_t*)(toread + 1));
    printf("Value: %d\n", val_read);
}
```

But this is not a good way to do it. If you want to read the parent data, you should just cast the pointer to a `struct Parent1*` and read it directly

```
void readParentData(struct Child* toread){
    printf("Byte size: %d\n", toread->size_bytes);
    int val_read = ((struct Parent1*)(toread))->val;
    printf("Value: %d\n", val_read);
}
```

Comment: The second approach doesn't work because `toread` could be an instance of any of the child classes (i.e. `Parent1` or `Parent2`). You can't assume it's a `Parent1`.

Comment: For that matter, the first approach doesn't work either since you assume the val is a `u_int16_t`, but it's a `u_int8_t` if provided a `Parent2`.

Comment: Both solutions work - but I'm still slightly confused why adding 1 to the pointer is offsetting by 1*sizeof(struct Child) rather than 1 byte. I thought pointers are a location in bytes, and adding 1 will just offset that by 1 byte.

Comment: @Waddles Pines, Adding one to a pointer will advance the pointer by the one of the size of that to which the pointer points. In this case, it advances it by the size of a `struct Child`.